# Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, header, stdafx.h

I am new to visual studio.I have created a simple console application and then selected an empty project of c++.Then pasted the following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include "GL/glut.h"      
#include "GL/glu.h"    
#include "GL/gl.h"   
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const float zNear = 0.05;
const float zFar = 500.0;
int width, height;
int draw = 0;
Point FIX_X(0, 0), FIX_Y(0, 0), FIX_Z(0, 0);
float skew_x, skew_y, skew_z;
VideoCapture cap(0);
Mat tmp, test;
Mat intrinsic_Matrix(3, 3, CV_64F);
Mat distortion_coeffs(8, 1, CV_64F);
Mat Projection(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
double largest_area;
int largest_contour_index;
int n = 0;
int no_of_fingers = 0;
vector<vector<pair<float, Point>>> position;
vector<int> finger_count;
Point first, second, third;
float size_of_pot = 10;
int rot_angle = 10;

float distanceP2P(Point a, Point b) {
    float d = sqrt(fabs(pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + pow(a.y - b.y, 2)));
    return d;
}
float getAngle(Point s, Point f, Point e) {
    float l1 = distanceP2P(f, s);
    float l2 = distanceP2P(f, e);
    float dot = (s.x - f.x)*(e.x - f.x) + (s.y - f.y)*(e.y - f.y);
    float angle = acos(dot / (l1*l2));
    angle = angle * 180 / 3.147;
    return angle;
}


String intToString(int number) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    string str = ss.str();
    return str;
}

bool pairCompare(const pair<float, Point>&i, const pair<float, Point>&j) {
    return i.first <j.first;

}

GLfloat* convertMatrixType(const cv::Mat& m)
{
    typedef double precision;

    Size s = m.size();
    GLfloat* mGL = new GLfloat[s.width*s.height];

    for (int ix = 0; ix < s.width; ix++)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < s.height; iy++)
        {
            mGL[ix*s.height + iy] = m.at<precision>(iy, ix);
        }
    }

    return mGL;
}

void generateProjectionModelview(const cv::Mat& calibration, const cv::Mat& rotation, const cv::Mat& translation, cv::Mat& projection, cv::Mat& modelview)
{
    typedef double precision;

    projection.at<precision>(0, 0) = 2 * calibration.at<precision>(0, 0) / width;
    projection.at<precision>(1, 0) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(2, 0) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(3, 0) = 0;

    projection.at<precision>(0, 1) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(1, 1) = 2 * calibration.at<precision>(1, 1) / height;
    projection.at<precision>(2, 1) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(3, 1) = 0;

    projection.at<precision>(0, 2) = 1 - 2 * calibration.at<precision>(0, 2) / width;
    projection.at<precision>(1, 2) = -1 + (2 * calibration.at<precision>(1, 2) + 2) / height;
    projection.at<precision>(2, 2) = (zNear + zFar) / (zNear - zFar);
    projection.at<precision>(3, 2) = -1;

    projection.at<precision>(0, 3) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(1, 3) = 0;
    projection.at<precision>(2, 3) = 2 * zNear*zFar / (zNear - zFar);
    projection.at<precision>(3, 3) = 0;


    modelview.at<precision>(0, 0) = rotation.at<precision>(0, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(1, 0) = rotation.at<precision>(1, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(2, 0) = rotation.at<precision>(2, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(3, 0) = 0;

    modelview.at<precision>(0, 1) = rotation.at<precision>(0, 1);
    modelview.at<precision>(1, 1) = rotation.at<precision>(1, 1);
    modelview.at<precision>(2, 1) = rotation.at<precision>(2, 1);
    modelview.at<precision>(3, 1) = 0;

    modelview.at<precision>(0, 2) = rotation.at<precision>(0, 2);
    modelview.at<precision>(1, 2) = rotation.at<precision>(1, 2);
    modelview.at<precision>(2, 2) = rotation.at<precision>(2, 2);
    modelview.at<precision>(3, 2) = 0;

    modelview.at<precision>(0, 3) = translation.at<precision>(0, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(1, 3) = translation.at<precision>(1, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(2, 3) = translation.at<precision>(2, 0);
    modelview.at<precision>(3, 3) = 1;

    // This matrix corresponds to the change of coordinate systems.
    static double changeCoordArray[4][4] = { { 1, 0, 0, 0 },{ 0, -1, 0, 0 },{ 0, 0, -1, 0 },{ 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
    static Mat changeCoord(4, 4, CV_64FC1, changeCoordArray);

    modelview = changeCoord*modelview;
}


void calibrate(Mat &intrinsic_Matrix, Mat &distortion_coeffs)
{

    vector< vector< Point2f> > AllimagePoints;
    vector< vector< Point3f> > AllobjectPoints;
    char str[100];
    stringstream st;
    int no_of_images = 1;
    Size imagesize;
    Mat gray;
    while (no_of_images <= 14)
    {
        st << "E:/SelectedImages/Selected" << ++no_of_images << ".jpg";
        String strcopy3 = st.str();
        st.str("");
        Mat img = imread(strcopy3, 1);
        if (!img.data)
            break;
        imagesize = Size(img.rows, img.cols);
        cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        vector< Point2f> corners;
        bool sCorner = false;
        sCorner = findChessboardCorners(gray, Size(7, 7), corners);
        if (sCorner)
        {

            cornerSubPix(gray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(img, Size(7, 7), corners, sCorner);
            if (corners.size() == 7 * 7)
            {
                vector< Point2f> v_tImgPT;
                vector< Point3f> v_tObjPT;
                for (int j = 0; j< corners.size(); ++j)
                {
                    Point2f tImgPT;
                    Point3f tObjPT;

                    tImgPT.x = corners[j].x;
                    tImgPT.y = corners[j].y;

                    tObjPT.x = j % 7 * 3;
                    tObjPT.y = j / 7 * 3;
                    tObjPT.z = 0;

                    v_tImgPT.push_back(tImgPT);
                    v_tObjPT.push_back(tObjPT);
                }
                AllimagePoints.push_back(v_tImgPT);
                AllobjectPoints.push_back(v_tObjPT);
            }

        }
        st << "E:/DetectedImages/Detected" << no_of_images + 1 << ".jpg";
        String strcopy1 = st.str();
        st.str("");
        imwrite(strcopy1, img);
        //imshow("pattern",img);
        //cvWaitKey(30);
    }
    vector< Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
    if (AllimagePoints.size()>0)
    {
        calibrateCamera(AllobjectPoints, AllimagePoints, imagesize, intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
    }

}


void renderBackgroundGL(const cv::Mat& image)
{

    GLint polygonMode[2];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, polygonMode);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_FILL);


    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    static bool textureGenerated = false;
    static GLuint textureId;
    if (!textureGenerated)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &textureId);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        textureGenerated = true;
    }

    // Copy the image to the texture.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.size().width, image.size().height, 0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);

    // Draw the image.
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Clear the depth buffer so the texture forms the background.
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Restore the polygon mode state.
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, polygonMode[0]);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, polygonMode[1]);
}




void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    namedWindow("live", 1);
    Mat gray1, test, modelview, dis_img, thresh, img1;

    Mat rvec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type);
    Mat tvec(3, 1, DataType<double>::type);

    modelview.create(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
    //Projection.create(4, 4, CV_64FC1);

    vector< Point2f> corners1;
    vector< Point2f> imagePoints1;
    vector< Point3f> objectPoints1;
    largest_area = 0;
    largest_contour_index = 0;

    clock_t clock_1 = clock();
    cap >> dis_img;
    //resize(dis_img,dis_img,Size(180,180),0,0);
    if (!dis_img.data)
    {
        exit(3);
    }
    img1 = dis_img.clone();
    dis_img.copyTo(img1);
    //resize(img1,img1,Size(180,180),0,0);
    cvtColor(dis_img, dis_img, COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
    inRange(dis_img, Scalar(0, 133, 77), Scalar(255, 173, 127), thresh);
    clock_t clock_2 = clock();
    cout << "threshold(Skin Color Segmentation) time is :" << (double)(clock_2 - clock_1) << endl;
    dilate(thresh, thresh, Mat());
    blur(thresh, thresh, Size(5, 5), Point(-1, -1), BORDER_DEFAULT);
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Point> FingerTips;
    vector<Vec4i> hierachy;
    vector<Vec4i> defects;
    vector<Point> defect_circle;
    vector<vector<Point>> hull(1);
    Point2f  center;
    float radius;
    clock_t clock_3 = clock();
    cout << "image filtering (smoothing) time is :" << (double)(clock_3 - clock_2) << endl;


    findContours(thresh, contours, hierachy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    //cout<<"contour"<<endl; 
    int cont_size = contours.size();
    for (int i = 0; i<cont_size; i++)
    {
        double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);
        if (a>largest_area)
        {
            largest_area = a;
            largest_contour_index = i;
        }
    }

    vector<int> hull_index;
    Rect brect;

    if (largest_area>0 && contours[largest_contour_index].size()>5)
    {

        approxPolyDP(contours[largest_contour_index], contours[largest_contour_index], 8, true);
        //cout<<"approx_poly"<<endl;
        convexHull(Mat(contours[largest_contour_index]), hull[0], false, true);
        //  cout<<"convex_hull"<<endl;
        brect = boundingRect(contours[largest_contour_index]);
        //cout<<"bounding_rect"<<endl;
        convexHull(Mat(contours[largest_contour_index]), hull_index, true);
        //cout<<"convex_hull2"<<endl;
        convexityDefects(contours[largest_contour_index], hull_index, defects);
        //cout<<"convexity defect"<<endl;
        // Mom ents mom=moments(contours[largest_contour_index]);
        // draw mass center
        //  circle(img,Point(mom.m10/mom.m00,mom.m01/mom.m00),2,cv::Scalar(0),2);


        Scalar colorw = Scalar(0, 255, 0);
        Scalar color1 = Scalar(0, 0, 255);
        //drawContours(img,contours,largest_contour_index,color,2, 8, hierachy);
        //drawContours(timg,contours,largest_contour_index,color,1, 8, hierachy);
        //drawContours(timg, hull, 0, color1, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
        //  drawContours(img, hull, 0, color1, 2, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
        int defc_size = defects.size();

        Point ptStart;
        Point ptEnd;
        Point ptStart2;
        Point ptEnd2;
        Point ptFar;
        int count = 1;
        int startidx2;
        int endidx2;
        int tolerance = brect.height / 5;
        float angleTol = 95;
        for (int in = 0; in<defc_size; in++)
        {
            //Vec4i& v=(*d); d++;
            int startidx = defects[in].val[0]; ptStart = contours[largest_contour_index].at(startidx);
            int endidx = defects[in].val[1]; ptEnd = contours[largest_contour_index].at(endidx);
            int faridx = defects[in].val[2];  ptFar = contours[largest_contour_index].at(faridx);
            if (in + 1<defc_size)
                startidx2 = defects[in + 1].val[0]; ptStart = contours[largest_contour_index].at(startidx);
            endidx2 = defects[in + 1].val[1]; ptEnd = contours[largest_contour_index].at(endidx);

            if (distanceP2P(ptStart, ptFar) > tolerance && distanceP2P(ptEnd, ptFar) > tolerance && getAngle(ptStart, ptFar, ptEnd) < angleTol) {
                {
                    if (in + 1<defc_size)
                    {
                        if (distanceP2P(ptStart, ptEnd2) < tolerance)
                            contours[largest_contour_index][startidx] = ptEnd2;
                        else {
                            if (distanceP2P(ptEnd, ptStart2) < tolerance)
                                contours[largest_contour_index][startidx2] = ptEnd;

                        }
                    }
                    defect_circle.push_back(ptFar);
                    //  cout<<"ptfar"<<ptFar.x<<"&&"<<ptFar.y<<endl;

                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        FingerTips.push_back(ptStart);
                        cv::circle(img1, ptStart, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                        putText(img1, intToString(count), ptStart - Point(0, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.2f, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
                    }
                    FingerTips.push_back(ptEnd);
                    count++;
                    putText(img1, intToString(count), ptEnd - Point(0, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.2f, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
                    cv::circle(img1, ptEnd, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                    //cv::circle( img, ptFar,   2, Scalar(255,255,255 ), 2 );

                }
            }
        }
        //  circle(img, ptStart,2,Scalar(0xFF,0x60,0x02 ), 2, 8, 0 );

        //cv::circle( img, ptEnd,   4, Scalar( 0xFF,0x60,0x02 ), 2 );
        clock_t clock_4 = clock();
        cout << "fingerTip detection  time is :" << (double)(clock_4 - clock_3) << endl;

        //  cout<<"hii"<<endl;
        bool two_fn = false;
        bool five_fn = false;

        if (defect_circle.size() == 1)
        {
            two_fn = true;
            Point fn = FingerTips.back();
            FingerTips.pop_back();
            Point ln = FingerTips.back();
            FingerTips.pop_back();
            Point defect_point = defect_circle.back();
            float curr = getAngle(fn, defect_point, ln);
            curr = curr / 10;
            curr = 10 - curr;
            renderBackgroundGL(img1);
            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(9, 6, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(defect_point);

            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(9, 6, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(defect_point);



            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(19, 6, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(fn);

            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(9, 18, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(ln);


            // cout<<width<<"  &"<<height<<endl;
            //  cout<<"solvepnp"<<endl; 
            solvePnP(Mat(objectPoints1), Mat(imagePoints1), intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvec, tvec);



            cv::Mat rotation;
            cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rotation);
            double offsetA[3][1] = { 9,6,6 };
            Mat offset(3, 1, CV_64FC1, offsetA);
            tvec = tvec + rotation*offset;


            generateProjectionModelview(intrinsic_Matrix, rotation, tvec, Projection, modelview);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            GLfloat* projection = convertMatrixType(Projection);
            glLoadMatrixf(projection);
            delete[] projection;

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            GLfloat* modelView = convertMatrixType(modelview);
            glLoadMatrixf(modelView);
            delete[] modelView;

            //glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
            glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

            glutWireTeapot(10.0 / curr);
            glPopMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        }
        //Rotation Module
        if (defect_circle.size() == 4)
        {

            five_fn = true;
            minEnclosingCircle(defect_circle, center, radius);
            //circle(img, center, (int)radius,Scalar(255,255,255), 2, 8, 0 );
            circle(img1, center, 2, Scalar(0), 2, 8, 0);

            vector<pair<float, Point>> pos;
            for (int in = 0; in<FingerTips.size(); in++)
            {
                Point p = FingerTips.back();
                FingerTips.pop_back();

                //if(in==0)
                //{
                pos.push_back(make_pair(distanceP2P(center, p), p));
                //position.push_back(pos);
            }
            //  }
            //else
            //  {
            //      cout<<"size is"<<position.size()<<endl;
            //  position[n].push_back(make_pair(distanceP2P(center,p),p));
            //}

            sort(pos.begin(), pos.end(), pairCompare);
            //  vector<pair<float,Point>> now=position[i].back();
            first = pos.back().second;
            pos.pop_back();
            //cout<<"new value :"<<new1.x<<" && "<<new1.y<<endl;
            second = pos.back().second;
            pos.pop_back();
            third = pos.back().second;
            pos.pop_back();

            if (third.y<second.y&&second.y<first.y)
            {
                //  cout<<"vertical pose"<<endl;
                FIX_X.x = center.x + 40;
                FIX_X.y = center.y;

                FIX_Y.x = center.x;
                FIX_Y.y = center.y - 40;
            }
            skew_x = getAngle(first, center, FIX_X);
            skew_y = getAngle(third, center, FIX_Y);
            cout << skew_x << "&" << skew_y << endl;
            if (first.x<img1.cols)
                line(img1, center, first, Scalar(200, 200, 200), 2, 8, 0);
            line(img1, center, FIX_X, Scalar(200, 200, 200), 2, 8, 0);
            if (second.x<img1.cols)
                line(img1, center, second, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
            if (third.x<img1.cols)
                line(img1, center, third, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);
            line(img1, center, FIX_Y, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);

            //  line(img1,center,first,Scalar(255,255,255),2,8,0);
            //  line(img1,center,second,Scalar(0,255,255),2,8,0);
            //  line(img1,center,third,Scalar(0,0,255),2,8,0);

            renderBackgroundGL(img1);

            /*  cvtColor(test, gray1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
            bool sCorner1=findChessboardCorners(gray1, Size(7, 7), corners1);
            imshow("live",test);
            if(sCorner1)
            {
            cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, Size(11,11), Size(-1,-1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            if(corners1.size() == 7*7)
            {control pan

            for(int j=0; j< corners1.size(); ++j)
            {
            Point2f tImgPT;
            Point3f tObjPT;

            tImgPT.x = corners1[j].x;
            tImgPT.y = corners1[j].y;

            tObjPT.x = j%7*3;
            tObjPT.y = j/7*3;
            tObjPT.z = 0;
            imagePoints1.push_back(tImgPT);
            objectPoints1.push_back(tObjPT);
            }

            vector<Point2f> projectedPoints;
            vector<Point3f> axis;

            axis.push_back(Point3f(6,0,0));
            axis.push_back(Point3f(0,6,0));
            axis.push_back(Point3f(0,0,6));  */
            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(9, 6, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(center);

            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(9, 18, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(first);

            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(19, 6, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(third);

            objectPoints1.push_back(Point3d(15, 15, 0));
            imagePoints1.push_back(second);


            // cout<<width<<"  &"<<height<<endl;
            //  cout<<"solvepnp"<<endl; 
            solvePnP(Mat(objectPoints1), Mat(imagePoints1), intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvec, tvec);



            cv::Mat rotation;
            cv::Rodrigues(rvec, rotation);
            double offsetA[3][1] = { 9,6,0 };
            Mat offset(3, 1, CV_64FC1, offsetA);
            tvec = tvec + rotation*offset;


            generateProjectionModelview(intrinsic_Matrix, rotation, tvec, Projection, modelview);

            /*  double offsetA[3][1] = {{(7-1.0)/2.0}, {(7-1.0)/2.0}, {0}};
            Mat offset(3, 1, CV_64FC1, offsetA);
            tvec = tvec + rotation*offset;

            for(unsigned int row=0; row<3; ++row)
            {
            for(unsigned int col=0; col<3; ++col)
            {
            modelview.at<float>(row, col) = rotation.at<float>(row, col);
            cout<<modelview.at<float>(row,col)<<endl;
            }
            modelview.at<float>(row, 3) = tvec.at<float>(row, 0);
            }
            modelview.at<float>(3, 3) = 1.0f;
            cout<<endl;



            static float changeCoordArray[4][4] = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
            static Mat changeCoord(4, 4, CV_64FC1, changeCoordArray);

            modelview = changeCoord*modelview;

            cv::Mat glmodelview = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64F);
            transpose(modelview , glmodelview);
            gluLookAt(0.0,2.0,-50.0,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
            /*  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            float fx=intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(0,0);
            float fy=intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(1,1);
            float cf=(2*atanf(0.5*height/fy)*180/3.14);
            float aspect=(width*fy)/(height*fx);

            //gluPerspective(cf,1.0, zNear, zFar);



            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

            glLoadMatrixf(&glmodelview.at<float>(0,0));  */
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            GLfloat* projection = convertMatrixType(Projection);
            glLoadMatrixf(projection);
            delete[] projection;

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            GLfloat* modelView = convertMatrixType(modelview);
            glLoadMatrixf(modelView);
            delete[] modelView;

            //glTranslat ef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
            glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glRotatef(skew_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glRotatef(skew_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glutWireTeapot(10.0);
            glPopMatrix();
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            clock_t clock_5 = clock();
            cout << "interaction time is :" << (double)(clock_5 - clock_4) << endl;
        }
        imshow("live", img1);
        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;

        glFlush();
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
    waitKey(27);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void reshape(int x, int y)
{
    width = x; height = y;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    /*Projection.at<float>(0,0) = 2*intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(0,0)/width;
    Projection.at<float>(1,0) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(2,0) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(3,0) = 0;

    Projection.at<float>(0,1) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(1,1) = 2*intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(1,1)/height;
    Projection.at<float>(2,1) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(3,1) = 0;

    Projection.at<float>(0,2) = 1-2*intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(0,2)/width;
    Projection.at<float>(1,2) = -1+(2*intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(1,2)+2)/height;
    Projection.at<float>(2,2) = (zNear+zFar)/(zNear - zFar);
    Projection.at<float>(3,2) = -1;

    Projection.at<float>(0,3) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(1,3) = 0;
    Projection.at<float>(2,3) = 2*zNear*zFar/(zNear - zFar);
    Projection.at<float>(3,3) = 0;

    cv::Mat projection = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64F);
    transpose(Projection ,projection);
    glLoadMatrixf(&projection.at<float>(0,0));   */


    // gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0, 100.0); 

    /* float fx=intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(0,0);
    float fy=intrinsic_Matrix.at<float>(1,1);
    float cf=(2*atanf(0.5*height/fy)*180/3.14);
    cout<<fx<<"   "<<fy<<endl;
    float aspect=(width*fy)/(height*fx);  */
    //gluPerspective(cf,CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO, zNear, zFar); 


    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //  gluPerspective(60,width/height, zNear, zFar);  
    //glOrtho(-100,100,-100.0,100,zNear, zFar);

}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
void main()
{
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    cap >> test;
    if (!test.data)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    //  resize(test,test,Size(180,180),0,0);
    width = test.cols;
    height = test.rows;
    cout << width << endl;
    calibrate(intrinsic_Matrix, distortion_coeffs);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("code4change");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

But when i compile the cide it always get error message "Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h'".What should i do?.As i know stdafx.h is a c++ headerfile.

Comment: Is the header file 'stdafx.h' installed or available in your libraries directory? It clearly isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the file in your project. If you don't (you have removed it by mistake) just create a new temporary project and copy it.

Comment: Or just remove the `#include`, not every project needs a precompiled header.

Comment: I supposed he needs it since he hasn't done so already, but you are right.

Comment: I suppose OP doesn't, because the other includes are not in `stdafx.h`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out It's not necessary to include "stdafx.h" header file in your program.It's used in Microsoft Visual Studio to let the compiler know the files that are once compiled and no need to compile it from scratch.

for better understanding you can refer 
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1TUq5Di1/

Answer (score 1):

Error C1083 Showing because you have included "stdafx.h" (#include "stdafx.h") but you don't have the file in your project. Add stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp (Project->add->existing file) from other solution if present solution don't have
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable precompiled headers in all configurations for all *.cpp files. It can be done on the "Precompiled Header" tab:

   - Set the value "Use (/Yu)" for the "Precompiled Header" option.
   - Set "stdafx.h" for the "Precompiled Header File" option.
   - Set "$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch" for the "Precompiled Header Output File" 
     option.
2. Create an stdafx.h file, and add it into the project.
3. Create an stdafx.cpp file, and add it into the project. This file has only one line: #include "stdafx.h".
4. Change the settings for the stdafx.cpp file in all configurations; set the value "Create (/Yc)" for the "Precompiled Header" option.

Reference: https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0265/

Well explained article about precompilation error.
Also sums up the process of usage and common errors faced and their solutions. Hope this is helpful.