# How to create folder in %appdata%, create .bat file in it, and then execute it?

Tags: c++

I'm creating C++ code that will create some `.bat` file and store it in the `%appdata%` folder. I've successfully to created the file, but still fail to create the folder and execute it.

Below is my simple code, it doesn't look simple but it works to create `.bat` file in `%appdata%`, maybe someone can help me to find the simple one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <direct.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using namespace std;
  std::ofstream aaa;
  ostringstream aaa;
  aaa.open(aaa1.str());
  aaa1 << getenv("appdata") << "/"
       << "test.bat";
  aaa.open(aaa1.str());
  Updater << "@echo on" << endl;
  Updater << "echo \"on\"" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code successfully creates the `.bat` file in `%appdata%`, but I need to store in new folder in `%appdata%`, say `New Folder`, and then execute the `.bat` file.

Comment: Please name your variables properly, also you have both an ofstream and ostringstream name 'aaa'?

Comment: You should use [SHGetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) to get the AppData folder on Windows older than Windows Vista. Or the [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) function on >= Windows Vista.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937227/create-directory-in-c) could help you a lot.

Comment: @Tom, sory but i'm still new in C++, and that code i got from many source, maybe you can help me the simple one..

Comment: @Neijwiert i've read that and still confuse to start, and then i got that code above using getenv

Comment: @Achilles29 Oh also, be sure to always check the state of C++ file streams. By default you do not get exceptions if they fail, they simply silently don't write anything. When you have successfully opened an output file, `good()` should be true, as well as when you are done writing.

Answer (score 0):

Creating/running an executable in a user writable location is something to be careful with (exploit people into running your process elevated, then running an attack payload), otherwise just a couple of things to tie together.

On Windows, most of those environment variables exist for legacy / compatibility reasons, [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) is the modern way to find the folders. It allocates enough space for the path, be careful with manual memory from C-API, get it a `unique_ptr` or `wstring` as soon as possible. It works from Vista, there are older API's if really needed.

```
wchar_t *str = nullptr;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &str); // CHECK RETURN
...use str...
CoTaskMemFree(str);
```

Also be aware of Unicode and spaces in file paths.

Processes have two options, there is the [`system(command_line)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) in the `cstdlib` header, or for advanced use check out the Windows [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). Something like:

```
STARTTUPINFO startup;
startup.cb = sizeof(startup);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcessW(NULL, L"cmd.exe /C C:\\ThePath\\myfile.bat", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startup, &pi);
```

Obviously specific to Windows. Linux, Mac, etc. have their own filesystem layouts and security.

C++ `fstream` won't create directories for you automatically. You could set up such directories as part of an installer, but to do it at runtime C++17 has [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), which takes a path. If you can't use C++17, use [`CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectoryw) or [`_mkdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir-wmkdir?view=vs-2019). Again on Windows be aware of Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Directory**
**1st** get the path using _dupenv_s() in string add new folder name "\New Folder"
**2nd** Create Directory using _mkdir(str.c_str());
**3rd** Create "test.bat" using std::ofstream outf(str);

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<direct.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{

 
 char *pValue;
 size_t len;
 
 
 errno_t err = _dupenv_s(&pValue, &len, "APPDATA");
 std::string NewFile = "\\new";

 

 std::string str(pValue);
 str = str + NewFile;

 _mkdir(str.c_str());

 str = str + "\\Sample.bat"; //
 std::ofstream outf(str);
 if (!outf)
 {
  printf("error ");
 }

 outf << "this is line1" << endl;
 outf << "line 2" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Please! Don't Forgot to Vote If its Helps

Comment: is "stdafx.h" necessary? i didnt find it yet. if i try without "stdafx.h" error says entry point must be defined.. @akash das

Comment: Please see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845899/error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stdafx-h-no-such-file-or-directory/55281046#55281046

Comment: @Achilles29 Go to <Project>Property >  Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Recompiled Headers > Recompiled Header > Not Using Recompiled Headers
Please see this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845899/error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stdafx-h-no-such-file-or-directory/55281046#55281046